# Setting physical (screen) size of an axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I thought this problem would be trivial but I haven't been able to figure it out. I have two 3D figures, representing two data sets that are of different physical size (ie. one might represent something 10cm wide, one 20cm wide). I non-dimensionalize everything (so width goes from 0 to 1) and then I use daspect to change the aspect ratio of the plot so that the width appears to change between the plots, even though the axis limits do not (I set these to be constant).

When I plot them, in different figures, however, MATLAB automatically scales the axis to fit in the figure. This means that my objects change size slightly, whilst I want them to keep the x and z scales exactly the same.

Is there some way I can manually set how many pixels one unit of an axis takes up? You can see in the images that the scales on the z axis of the two figures are different, ie. the same length in zaxis units takes up different lengths in pixels.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

The code I used for the axes, view, and aspect ratio is:

```
xlim([-0.3 .6])
ylim([-.8 .8])
zlim([-0.2 1.3])

view([60 15])

daspect([1/268.3 1/(99.9730*width) 1/74])
```

James

Comment: The size of the z axis is a function of the size of the axes object (defined in the Position property of the axis) and of the axes rotation (in the View property).  Since one of your plots is rotated relative to the other, the z axis scales so that the axis takes up the same height.  Here the top corner and bottom corner of the axes box is the same length in both plots.  How the axes View and Properties yields a z axis length is a trig problem to figure out.

Comment: The rotation is set to the same angle (az and el) though. And the zaxes do not take up the same height. The narrow is 209 pixels, the wide is 193 pixels. The ratio between these two is, of course, the same as the ratio between the body heights I put in the image.

Comment: you should include some of your code, specially the part when you define the aspect ratio and the limits

Comment: Added code for lims, etc.